# How do I make my chatbot recognize a blank response? How do I make it work with multiple spaces?

Tags: java

Here are the instructions from my class:

Currently, the program gives a random response if the user types nothing.  Make it so that an empty input causes the program to respond with, "Say something, please."  To help you with this, learn what the trim() method from the String class does.   (Look it up in your textbook or online.)  Notice that if you trim() a String of all blanks, you will get an empty String as a result.   Use this to ensure that you respond appropriately if the user types three blank spaces!

Code:

```
public class Magpie2
{
    /**
     * Get a default greeting   
     * @return a greeting
     */
    public String getGreeting()
    {
        return "Hello, let's talk.";
    }

    /**
     * Gives a response to a user statement
     * 
     * @param statement
     *            the user statement
     * @return a response based on the rules given
     */
    public String getResponse(String statement)
    {
        String response = "";
        if (findKeyword(statement,"no") >= 0)
        {
            response = "Why so negative?";
        }
        else if (findKeyword(statement,"mother") >= 0
                || findKeyword(statement,"father") >= 0
                || findKeyword(statement,"sister") >= 0
                || findKeyword(statement,"brother") >= 0)
        {
            response = "Tell me more about your family.";
        }
        else if (findKeyword(statement,"cat") >= 0
                || findKeyword(statement,"dog") >= 0)
        {
            response = "Tell me more about your pets.";
        }
        else if (findKeyword(statement,"Levine") >= 0)
        {
            response = "Tell me more about your instructor.";
        }
        else if (findKeyword(statement,"phone") >= 0
                || findKeyword(statement,"cellphone") >= 0
                || findKeyword(statement,"iphone") >= 0)
        {
            response = "I'm smarter than your phone.";
        }
        else if (findKeyword(statement,"I want to") >= 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            response = getRandomResponse();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the explanation.

"Notice that if you trim() a String of all blanks, you will get an empty String as a result."

Extend your if/else statements to include an else if that checks the condition such that statement.trim() is equal to "".

Comment: How should it look in code? else if (statement.trim(" ") >= 0) doesn't seem to work

Comment: trim a method for String Class that doesn't take any parameters. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim() You will want to look at the api. Also it looks like you are trying to compare the length, which would be done like this: statement.trim().length() == 0